# Model for Post Request Edit Action Not being filled in by Model given by Get Request Edit Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a ProductController with an Edit Action GetRequest and an Edit Action PostRequest .

The Edit GetRequest Action gets an individual Product entity based on route ID value from the request and builds a ProductViewModel. I have implicit conversion methods for these.

The View returned builds a ProductEditViewModel with the values fro the ProductViewModel:

```
    // GET: Product/Edit/5
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {

        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        ProductViewModel product = await db.Products.FindAsync(id);

        var categoryID = db.Categories.Single(c => c.Products.Any(p => p.Id == id)).Id;

        if (product == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(new ProductEditViewModel { Id = product.Id, Name = product.Name, ByteImage = product.ByteImage, Price = product.Price, CategoryId = categoryID});
    }
```

I have access to the Edit GetRequest page when running my applicion and can see a Product displayed successfully to edit, however, when I send back a Post request, the ProductEditViewModel that is given to the Edit PostRequest Action is empty. It should have the Name and Id properties filled in as the Image can be left unchanged. Here is my Edit PostRequest Action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Image,Price")] ProductEditViewModel model)
    {

        var oldImage = db.Products.Where(p => p.Id == model.Id).Select(x => x.Image).FirstOrDefault();


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Product modifiedProduct = model;

            if(modifiedProduct.Image == null)
            {
                modifiedProduct.Image = oldImage;
            }
            db.Entry(modifiedProduct).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index/" + model.categoryID);
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

My ProductViewModels:

```
public class ProductViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required, Display(Name="Product Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
        public HttpPostedFileBase Image { get; set; }
        public string OutputImage { get; set; }
        public Byte[] ByteImage { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Decimal Price { get; set; } 
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        public static byte[] ConvertToByte(ProductViewModel model)
        {
            if (model.Image != null)
            {
                byte[] imageByte = null;
                BinaryReader rdr = new BinaryReader(model.Image.InputStream);
                imageByte = rdr.ReadBytes((int)model.Image.ContentLength);

                return imageByte;
            }

            return null;
        }

        // ViewModel => Model | Implicit type Operator
        public static implicit operator Product(ProductViewModel viewModel)
        {
            var model = new Product
            {
                Id = viewModel.Id,
                Name = viewModel.Name,
                Image = ConvertToByte(viewModel),
                Price = viewModel.Price
            };

            return model;
        }

    // Model => ViewModel | Implicit type Operator
    public static implicit operator ProductViewModel(Product model)
    {
        var viewModel = new ProductViewModel
        {
            Id = model.Id,
            Name = model.Name,
            OutputImage = string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(model.Image)),
            ByteImage = model.Image,
            Price = model.Price,
            CategoryId = model.Id
        };

        return viewModel;
    }

}
```

ProductEditViewModel:

```
public class ProductEditViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required, Display(Name = "Product Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    public HttpPostedFileBase Image { get; set; }
    public string OutputImage { get; set; }
    public byte[] ByteImage { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator ProductViewModel(ProductEditViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var model = new Product
        {
            Id = viewModel.Id,
            Name = viewModel.Name,
            Image = ConvertToByte(viewModel),
            Price = viewModel.Price
        };

        return model;
    }

    public static implicit operator ProductEditViewModel(ProductViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var model = new ProductEditViewModel
        {
            Id = viewModel.Id,
            Name = viewModel.Name,
            ByteImage = ConvertToByte(viewModel),
            Price = viewModel.Price
        };

        return model;
    }



    private static byte[] ConvertToByte(ProductEditViewModel viewModel)
    {

        if (viewModel.Image != null)
        {
            byte[] imageByte = null;
            BinaryReader rdr = new BinaryReader(viewModel.Image.InputStream);
            imageByte = rdr.ReadBytes((int)viewModel.Image.ContentLength);

            return imageByte;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: try passing just the `ProductEditViewModel model` to your `POST` action.

Comment: I agree with Elmer. The POST action should only take the viewmodel as parameter. So everything you need in your POST action should be on the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have the getters and setters for the ProductEditViewModel to be able to assign values.